# How to use RxJS in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way to write a code like that in angular 2?

```
var closeButton1 = document.querySelector('.close1');
var close1ClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(closeButton1, 'click');
```

I have tried many ways to put them in angular 2 component put it does not worked well!
I tried something like this

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('delete') closeButton1: ElementRef;

close1ClickStream = Observable.fromEvent(closeButton1, 'click');
```

component.html

```
<!-- this code is inside *ngFor -->
<li><a #delete [routerLink]="['/update', item.id]">delete</a></li>
```

The problem is that I can not access the element even if I used AfterContentInit. Moreover, if I could access it, can I use the `Observable.fromEvent(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directives to handle events

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[click-handler]'
})
export class ClickHandler {

   constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef,) {
   }

   @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
   onClick(e) {
     // do staff here 
   }
}
```

usage

```
 <button click-handler> click </button>
```

Anyway if you want to do it using Observables you will need 
`elementRef.nativeElement` which is available here , just implement `OnInit` method and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//...

@ViewChild('delete') closeButton1: ElementRef;

close1ClickStream = Observable.fromEvent(closeButton1, 'click');
```